# insertar datos desde un array javascript a mysql php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, array

tengo un formulario que me carga los datos en un array de js con la siguiente función:

```
function mostrarArticulos(){


    var cuerpoTabla=document.getElementById("datos_articulos");
    var tablaLlena ="";

    for (var i = 0; i < tabla.length; i++){
        tablaLlena += "<li class='list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center'>" + tabla[i].articulo + "<span class='badge badge-primary badge-pill'>" + tabla[i].cantidad + "</span>  </li>";
    }

    cuerpoTabla.innerHTML = tablaLlena; 
}
```

esa función me muestra los datos en una lista:

la que me guarda...es esta:

```
function nuevoArticulo(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var articuloIN = document.getElementById("articulo").value;
    var cantidadIN = document.getElementById("cantidad").value;

    var nuevoArticulo = {articulo: articuloIN, cantidad: cantidadIN };
    tabla.push(nuevoArticulo);
    mostrarArticulos();


}
```

mi duda es como volcar el contenido de esa array de js a una base de datos usando mysql y php.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que debes usar es Ajax para ello usa Jquery algo asi:

```
dataString = miArray ;
var json = JSON.stringify(dataString);
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mi_archivo.php",
        data: {data : json}, 
        cache: false,
        success: function(){
            alert("OK");
        }
    });
```

Ese seria la forma mas simple de como enviar tus datos por ajax hacia un archivo php ya en tu php lo harias algo asi:

```
  $data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));
  foreach($data as $d){
     echo $d;
  }
```

Si te fijas alli voy recorriendo la data enviaba desde ajax hacia Php en un foreach dentro de este haria la parte de insert o lo que deseo hacia mysql.

Para mayor referencia y detalle te sugiero revisar este tutorial:

[Send JavaScript Array to the AJAX using jQuery and PHP](https://makitweb.com/how-to-send-javascript-array-to-the-ajax-using-jquery-and-php/)
Suerte y espero te sirva..!!